# List<string> complex sorting

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, lambda, arraylist

I have a `List<string>` of sizes, say XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL, UK 10, UK 12 etc

What I want is to force the order to be that of above, regardless of the order of items in the list, I think I need a IComparable operator but unsure.

Ideally I want to have another List with the correct order in which it can reference it's 'place' in the list and re-sort itself, if it doesn't exist it will default to A-Z

Comment: @Tigran My guess? He wants to sort stuff with a custom `IComparer<T>`. For the second part? A `SortedDictionary` might work.

Comment: @Tigran Essentially I have a List<string> that contains:

XXXL, S, M, L in ANY order

I need them to be ordered how I state (perhaps in another list in correct order) so the outcome is:

S, M, L, XXXL

Comment: You might want to consider creating an enum and converting the values.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Create an array of sizes in the order you want them to be in, then sort the shirts by the position of their sizes in that array:

```
string[] sizes = new [] {"XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL", "UK 10", "UK 12"};

var shirtsInOrder = shirts
                        .OrderBy(s=>sizes.Contains(s) ? "0" : "1")  // put unmatched sizes at the end
                        .ThenBy(s=>Array.IndexOf(sizes,s))  // sort matches by size
                        .ThenBy(s=>s); // sort rest A-Z
```

Comment: [using a dictionary is preferable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13824361/1159478) to performing a linear search on an array.

Comment: I'm missing the _"if it doesn't exist it will default to A-Z"_

Comment: Thanks, how does the 2nd line work with the first? Also not sure where  s.Size is from?

Comment: I was providing an example with the assumption that you have a Shirt class with a Size property - it may not fit your specific usage, just an example.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. No, at the moment I current just have a List<string> rather than a class, may need to convert it in my code unless there's a simple solution?

Comment: @dhardy just take off the `.Size` (edited answer to reflect that)

Comment: It's working fine with the S, M, L chars but not the UK 10 etc ones, could it be because it has a number so isn't sorting that low to high?

Comment: Where should UK 10, UK12 ,etc. be in the ordered list?  You've got them at the end.  It will sort anything not in the list alphabetically (e.g. UK 11 will come before UK 8).  If you want them in a specific order add them to the list or write logic to parse them and sort them numerically.

Answer (score 3):

```
var order = new string[] { "XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL", "UK10", "UK12" };

var orderDict = order.Select((c, i) => new { sze = c, ord = i })
            .ToDictionary(o => o.sze, o => o.ord);

var list = new List<string> { "S", "L", "XL", "L", "L", "XS", "XL" };
var result = list.OrderBy(item => orderDict[item]);
```

Comment: Here also, I'm missing the _"if it doesn't exist it will default to A-Z"_

Comment: Thanks, it falls over if the value isn't present in the dictionary where I need it to sort by a-z if it isn't..

Answer (score 2):

You can use `OrderByDescending` + `ThenByDescending` directly:

```
sizes.OrderByDescending(s => s == "XS")
     .ThenByDescending( s => s == "S")
     .ThenByDescending( s => s == "M")
     .ThenByDescending( s => s == "L")
     .ThenByDescending( s => s == "XL")
     .ThenByDescending( s => s == "XXL")
     .ThenByDescending( s => s == "UK 10")
     .ThenByDescending( s => s == "UK 12")
     .ThenBy(s => s);
```

I use `...Descending` since a `true` is similar to 1 whereas a `false` is 0.

Comment: Similarly, when I want to sort a list of `uint`s I do `var sorted = myUints.OrderByDescending(mu => mu == 0); for (uint u = 1; u < 1000; u++) sorted = sorted.ThenByDescending(s => s == u); sorted = sorted.ThenBy(s => s);`

Comment: Thanks Tim, it's ordering the S, M, L etc ok but not the UK 6, UK 8 etc, could it be due to the numbers?

Comment: @dhardy: How do you want to order the UK numbers? I thought there were only the two (UK 10 and UK 12).

Comment: This is the order I need: "15", "15.5", "16", "16,5", "17", "17.5", "18", "18.5", "19", "UK 6", "UK 8", "UK 10", "UK 12", "UK 14", "UK 16", "XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL" thanks, Dave

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something like this:

```
public class ShirtComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private static readonly string[] Order = new[] { "XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL", "UK10", "UK12" };

    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        var xIndex = Array.IndexOf(Order, x);
        var yIndex = Array.IndexOf(Order, y);

        if (xIndex == -1 || yIndex == -1) 
            return string.Compare(x, y, StringComparison.Ordinal);

        return xIndex - yIndex;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var list = new List<string> { "S", "L", "XL", "L", "L", "XS", "XL", "XXXL", "XMLS", "XXL", "AM19" };
var result = list.OrderBy(size => size, new ShirtComparer());
```

It should also default to A-Z for values not in the list...

Answer (score 0):

You can also create other list, and use a delegate to use with the sort, where you return if the index of size1 > index of size2.