# LINQ Order BY using literal values in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, sorting

I'm new to LINQ, would like to sort by a custom literal order... not sure of the syntax to do so (assuming it is possible). Thanks!

```
Class Foo
    Sub New(Name As String, Position As Integer)
        Me.Name = Name
        Me.Position = Position
    End Sub
    Public Name As String
    Public Position As Integer
End Class

Sub Main()
    Dim l As New List(Of Foo)
    l.Add(New Foo("Something1", 1))
    l.Add(New Foo("Something2", 2))
    l.Add(New Foo("Something3", 3))

Dim literalSort = ..... 'sort l by this literal order... "2, 3, 1"
```

Comment: are you trying to sort the contents of a List? What is the reason for it?

Comment: I'm not sure if you know the order in advance in order to hard code it literally why you can't just put them in that order to start with. Can you explain your situation?

Comment: So do you want the second item in the list to be first, or the item with a value of 2 to be first? I agree that I can't see a real world application of this so some explanation as to why you want to do this might yield a better solution

Comment: I have no control over the enumeration values. They are added sequentially overtime. The reason for the literal sort is for display purposes such as a grid; presenting the sort the user desires. Wanted to use LINQ to prepare the (custom) sort for any possible order requested of me.

Comment: BTW, the above example is not real-world, it simply a basis for the reply... simply looking for how to construct a LINQ statement in VB that specifies a non ASC/DESC Order By (a literal valued Order By). THANK YOU!

Comment: It sounds more like you're trying (in a backwards kind of way) implement a display order property. Where the user can drag items around to reorder them.  Don't try to "orderby" some strage list of numbers, just change the objects displayorder property instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13824369/1081897) to VB:

```
Dim order = New Integer() {2,3,1}

Dim literalSort = l.OrderBy(Function(i) If(order.Contains(i), 0, 1)) _ 
                   .ThenBy(Function(i) Array.IndexOf(order, i)) _
                   .ThenBy(Function(i) i)  ' sort rest numerically
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the seeming arbitrary nature of the ordering you want to achieve, I'd create a method with a case statement and then return the order you want, based on the position:

```
Public Function OrderFoo (ByVal foo as Foo) as Integer
    Select Case foo.Position
        Case 2 
            Return 1
        Case 3
            Return 2
        Case 1
            Return 3
        Case Else
            Return 100
    End Select
End Function
```

Call the method in the `OrderBy` in LINQ and make sure you document why you're choosing the ordering that you are.

You should be able to call the method like below:

```
From foo In l _
Select foo _
Order By OrderFoo(foo)
```

Comment: Thanks Maurice! Since I am new the LINQ, what would the LINQ syntax look like to call the OrderFoo function in Order By?

Comment: Awesome Maurice, TY! Your answer or D. Stanley's answer will do nicely! Thank you everyone for your contribution. -c

Comment: My pleasure.  Please make sure to mark either my or D Stanley's answer as the accepted one so they get credit, and as I pointed out, please make sure you comment the reason you're doing the ordering the way you are, just so the next guy understands why you did what you did.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This will create a new list ordered as specified in the orderedNumbers array:

```
    Dim l As New List(Of Foo)
    l.Add(New Foo("Something1", 1))
    l.Add(New Foo("Something2", 2))
    l.Add(New Foo("Something3", 3))

    Dim orderedNumbers As Integer() = {2, 3, 1}
    Dim outputList As New List(Of Foo)
    For Each num In orderedNumbers
        outputList.Add(l.Item(num - 1))
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need is a customer comparer that implements `IComparer(Of Foo)`.

The example that follows sorts the items in the list according to the `Value` which is what I have assumed you are after. It should be easier enough to change this if it is not exactly as you want.

```
Public Class SpecificListComparer
    Implements IComparer(Of Foo)
    Private _order As Integer() = {2, 3, 1}
    Public Function Compare(x As Foo, y As Foo) As Integer Implements IComparer(Of Foo).Compare
        'TODO - check for null values
        If x.Value = y.Value AndAlso x.Name = y.Name Then Return 0
        If x.Value = y.Value Then Return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name)
        Return Array.IndexOf(_order, x.Value).CompareTo(Array.IndexOf(_order, y.Value))
    End Function
End Class
```

Then you just use it like this:

```
l.Sort(New SpecificListComparer)
```